# OnDraw of SurfaceView calling period

Tags: android, surfaceview, ondraw

I am wondering what is the period of calling for the method OnDraw of a SurfaceView. Does it depends on the device?

For example, Is this method call 32, 24 or 16 times per second?

thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android will call `onDraw()` method of a view class ( e.g SurfaceView) each time the view needs to be refreshed. The number of times a view gets refreshed depends on the `Refresh Rate` of the device.

You can use [`getRefreshRate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRefreshRate%28%29) to get the refresh rate of  the display in frames per second.

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int refreshRate = display.getRefreshRate();
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I can use it also to measure time somehow, I don't need high accuracy, just to refres some Sprite.

Comment: The time interval between two calls to onDraw() will be 1000/refreshRate (i.e. divide total time in milliseconds by number of frames per second).